# How to pass variables between php scripts?

Tags: php, parameter-passing, arguments

Is there any way to pass values and variables between php scripts?

Formally, I tried to code a login page and when user enter wrong input first another script will check the input and if it is wrong, site returns to the last script page and show a warning like "It is wrong input". For this aim, I need to pass values from scripts I guess.

Regards... :P

Comment: PHP sessions? http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**To pass info via GET**:

```
    header('Location: otherScript.php?var1=val1&var2=val2');
```

**Session**:

```
    // first script
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['varName'] = 'varVal';
    header('Location: second_script.php'); // go to other

    // second script
    session_start(); 
    $myVar = $_SESSION['varName'];
```

**Post**: Take a look at [this](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm).

Answer (score 5):

You should look into [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).  This involves storing data on the server linked to a particular reference number (the "session id") which is then sent by the browser on each request (generally as a cookie).  The server can see that the same user is accessing the page, and it sets the `$_SESSION` superglobal to reflect this.

For instance:

**a.php**

```
session_start(); // must be called before data is sent

$_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Invalid input';

// redirect to b.php
```

**b.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['error_msg']; // outputs "Invalid input"
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, although I'm a little confused as to why you're supposed to use "session_start()" in b.php when it's more like "session_continue() since presumably it doesn't make a new session.

Comment: That's how it is. Without session_start(); you can't read the session variables.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you `include` (or `include_once` or `require`) the other script?

Comment: Do all the variables get passed across when you include a script, or just globals?

Comment: When you `include` another script, its code gets "pasted" in the including one, so it gets the same things you would have writing the code directly in the first one.

Comment: Thanks - is that different from require ?  I had tried require and did not seem to do that.

Comment: While if `include` can't find the specified file it will raise a warning, `require` will throw a fatal exception.

Answer (score 3):

The quick way would be to use either global or session variables.

```
global $variable = 'something';
```

The 'better' way of doing it would be to include the script and pass the variable by parameter like

```
// script1.php contains function 'add3'
function add3( $value ) {
  return $value + 3;
}

// script2.php
include "script1.php";
echo 'Value is '.add3(2); // Value is 5
```

Comment: This one is my favourite. Sometimes you cannot use sessions, but this way you don't even have to. The only thing is you have to do `global $variable; $variable = 'something';` so declaration and assignment are not in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could also store a variable in cache if you really need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- temporary file (e.g. [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)),
- cache (NoSQL: [`memcached`](http://memcached.org/), [`redis`](http://redis.io/)),
- session variable ([`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)), but you need to start the session first.

Answer (score 0):

I use `extract()` method to pass variable among **PHP Scripts**. It look like below example:

**1.** File **index.php**

```
<?php
$data = [
    'title'=>'hello',
    'content'=>'hello world'
];
extract($data);
require 'content.php';
```

**2.** File **content.php** :

```
<?php 
echo $title;
echo $content;
```