# Passing retrieved database records to a php file

Tags: php, mysql, include

**system/article.php**

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT articleTitle, articleSummary, articleContent FROM articles";
$result = $dbconnect->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["articleTitle"];
        echo $row["articleSummary"];
        echo $row["articleContent"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

include 'template/homepage.php';
```

retrieves articles from the article table.

I have included the homepage.php which is supposed to act as a template.

**template/homepage.php**

```
<?php include 'template/common/header.php'; ?>

  <h1>Article Title here</h1>
  <p>articleSummary</p>

<?php include 'template/common/footer.php'; ?>
```

How do I now pass the retrieved data to the homepage.php to display it on the browser ?

### **Edit**

smarber pointed me to

In the first file:

```
global $variable;
$variable = "apple";
include('second.php');
```

In the second file:

```
echo $variable;
```

which works. But how do I implement the same with my problem up top?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905140/php-pass-variable-to-include

Comment: To better help you, what is your intention to loop through the fetched data?

Comment: @someOne, need to publish all articles on the homepage in the table

Comment: It's vague! so, why don't you get the data directly from the homepage instead? (I mean why not to query the database in the homepage?)

Comment: @someOne, hmm, let me see what i end up with .... thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may [do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678703/3709765) via GET, Session or Post; But why don't you simply and efficiently define a function and pass those variables to it, just for example:

```
function displayArticle($title, $summary, $content) {
    displayHeader(); // maybe some concepts you've used in template/common/header.php
    echo "<h1>$title</h1><p>$summary</p><div>$content</div>";
    displayFooter(); // again, what you've provided in footer.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well then, you may do the following:

change the `template/homepage.php` file to:

```
<?php
include 'template/common/header.php';

echo "<h1>$articleName</h1>";
echo "<p>$articleSummary</p>";

include 'template/common/footer.php';
?>
```

and change the `system/article.php` to:

```
<?php 
global $articleName;
global $articleSummary;
global $articleContents;

$sql = "SELECT articleTitle, articleSummary, articleContent FROM articles";
$result = $dbconnect->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $articleName = $row["articleTitle"];
        $articleSummary = $row["articleSummary"];
        $articleContents = $row["articleContent"];

        include 'template/homepage.php';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

However, It's so better to create a cleaner and more reusable code using some facilities you have in the programming language, like using functions and classes :)

Comment: thank you, I do not know oop in php. Functions I can manage. You sure I should include 'template/homepage.php' within the while ()?

Comment: @ManishB Well, it's the logic of your original post, and I just preserved it; if you don't place the `include` there, and place it at the bottom of code, then it will only be carried out once the `while()` loop is over and regardless of the outer `if` statement and only applies for the **last** item fetched by the `fetch_assoc` (which ignores all the preceding data) :)

Comment: thanks man, guess will have to look for a better alternative.

Comment: @ManishB Your welcome, the procedural approach is very easy and intuitive and is the preferred way;

Comment: accepted your first answer, a request though, will be glad if you can guide me to an online tutorial, if possible.