# how to call another php file with parameters?

Tags: php

i want to export two different type of `xlsx file` based on radio button .

```
    $sel = $_POST['sel'];
       echo $sel;

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){

        if($sel == 'board')
        {
         header('Location: export_data1.php? 
       num='.$_POST['staff']);  
       die(); 
        }
       else
       {

         header('Location: export_data2.php? 
          num='.$_POST['desg']);
         die(); 

        }
       }
```

how to call another php file based on my radio button.Is there any other alternate way to call php file with passing arguments?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678567/how-to-pass-variables-between-php-scripts

Comment: i try that method not working in my form

Comment: An alternative could be to have bog standard links to your files.

Comment: What's the problem here, what isn't working?

Comment: An aside: you might want to url encode your query string.  See `url_encode` and/or `http_build_query`.

Comment: In principle I don't see what's wrong with your method here.

Comment: Don't output content before sending headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your page of form where you will create form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"method="post">
    <!-- radio button -->
    <input type="radio" name="sel" value="board">
    <input type="radio" name="sel" value="your_other_value">
    <!-- radio button -->
   <!-- Drop Down -->
    <input type="option" name="boardlist" value="board">
    <input type="option" name="desgwise" value="Designation">
    <!-- radio button -->

    <input type="hidden" name="staff">
    <input type="hidden" name="desg">
    <input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is your export_data1.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    if($sel == 'board'){
        header('Location: export_data.php?num='.$_POST['boardlist'];
    } else {
        header('Location: export_data1.php?num='.$_POST['desgwise'];
    }
}
?>
```

export_data & export_data1 have different format for export xlsx file

Comment: Is this Jeopardy?  What's different with this approach here?  What's `$sel`?

Comment: I assume the difference here is that instead of having two separate export scripts, you are merging them into one script.  I think I prefer the separation of responsibility, unless the code is practically identical.  Differentiated URLs could also be a good thing.

Comment: i separate into two files. action="export_data1.php?desg=<?php echo $desg ?>"   is it correct method to passing parameters