# Javascript Light Box that loads a PHP Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Background:** I am trying to understand how the following scenario actually happens.

I am using `colorbox.js` a light box script and when a user clicks the `<a class='ajax' href='edit_labor.php?edit_id=$id' title=''><span class='oi oi-pencil'>Edit</span></a>` link in any of the table rows a lightbox should pop-up and a php page (located on the server) should load inside the light box.

This happens but the child PHP page `edit_labor.php` can not access any of the variables set on the parent page `planned_labot.php`. Just to test the scope of the child page I am actually able to add an `include('functions.php');` in both the child page and the header of the parent page. Shouldn't I get errors from trying to load the same functions twice?

**Question:** I don't understand the parent child relationship between the loaded php page and the parent php page when jquery.colorbox.js loads it.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax").colorbox();    
    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
    });
  </script>
```

```css
/*
    Colorbox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
#cboxWrapper {max-width:none;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0; padding:0; margin:0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of Colorbox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0; opacity: 0.9; filter: alpha(opacity = 90);}
#colorbox{outline:0;}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -101px 0;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -130px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -101px -29px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -130px -29px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:21px; background:url(images/controls.png) left top repeat-y;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:21px; background:url(images/controls.png) right top repeat-y;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:21px; background:url(images/border.png) 0 0 repeat-x;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:21px; background:url(images/border.png) 0 -29px repeat-x;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:28px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#949494;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:58px; color:#949494;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url(images/loading_background.png) no-repeat center center;}
        #cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}

        /* these elements are buttons, and may need to have additional styles reset to avoid unwanted base styles */
        #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxSlideshow, #cboxClose {border:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:visible; width:auto; background:none; }
        
        /* avoid outlines on :active (mouseclick), but preserve outlines on :focus (tabbed navigating) */
        #cboxPrevious:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxSlideshow:active, #cboxClose:active {outline:0;}

        #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:4px; right:30px; color:#0092ef;}
        #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -75px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxPrevious:hover{background-position:-75px -25px;}
        #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:27px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -50px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxNext:hover{background-position:-50px -25px;}
        #cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -25px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxClose:hover{background-position:-25px -25px;}

/*
  The following fixes a problem where IE7 and IE8 replace a PNG's alpha transparency with a black fill
  when an alpha filter (opacity change) is set on the element or ancestor element.  This style is not applied to or needed in IE9.
  See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/
*/
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
}
```

```html
<?PHP
//I am also including this same file in edit_labot.php
include('functions.php');

//
$test_var_parent = "this is a test string that is undefined in edit_labor.php";

?>

<a class='ajax' href='edit_labor.php?edit_id=1' title=''><span class='oi oi-pencil'>Edit</span></a>
```

Above is the code and edit_labor.php when loaded tries to reference `$test_var_parent` but I get the undefined notice

Comment: If you show us the code, we might be able to follow what you're trying to do. With 2k in rep, you should know [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right sorry i got lazy. I have added the code I am referencing above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP variables are only meaningful in the server while they are being processed in order to generate the HTML you want.

As it is clearly evident, the parent page is loaded to the browser after the first PHP process and, the child page is loaded to the browser after the second PHP process takes place. There cannot be any cross access happen between the variables since the process happens separately and **in two different points in time**.

If your child page wants to access information generated by the parent page, let the parent page generate info and store them in global js variables. When the child page is loaded, its js can now access the global variables generated by the parent page.

The question below shows another approach. It depends on the circumstance which method you should use to share information between pages.

[How to pass variables between php scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678567/how-to-pass-variables-between-php-scripts)